# Intellij module dependency added, but still fails in compilation

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module, intellij-plugin

I have these two modules WEB and Database. I have set Database as a dependency for WEB. When I open the code in WEB, the imported Database is no longer in red. However, when I execute commands: clean, install, cargo:run, the code fails saying the imported code does not exist.

[image: picture of compilation]
[image: proof of dependency]

Edit

pom.xml in WEB module. It is still not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>LNU-Project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>WEB</artifactId>

    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>Database</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: can you add screenshots of pom files of both modules?

Comment: `I have set Database as a dependency for WEB.` how did you set this? Note that in case of a Maven project you must manage dependencies in Maven pom.xml files.